# How do you replace every character in a string variable without looping?

Tags: javascript

My aim is for a string passed into `dna` will be converted using the lookup table `traslateDna` and returned.

For a single character this works fine but multiple characters and empty strings breaks this.

I can get it to work running it through a loop but is there a way of not requiring a loop?

Sample `dna` = `ACGTGGT`

```
const traslateDna = {
  'G':'C',
  'C':'G',
  'T':'A',
  'A':'U'
}
export const toRna = (dna) => {
  let rnaStr = ''
  for(let i =0; i < dna.length; i++){
    rnaStr+=(traslateDna[dna[i]])
  }
  return rnaStr; 
};
```

Below is the closest I can come, which is pretty awful. Is there a way of using the `replace()`method for this.

```
const traslateDna = {
  'G':'C',
  'C':'G',
  'T':'A',
  'A':'U'
}
export const toRna = (dna) => {
  let rnaStr = '';
    rnaStr = traslateDna[dna.replace()]);
  }
  return rnaStr; 
};
```

Comment: I'm confused... this code would be invalid no matter how to slice it. its not valid javascript

Comment: Poorly worded first attempt. Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is still incorrect. You should put it into codepen and try to parse it. It should not run.

To answer your question tho, You could use recursion I suppose.

```js
const dna = 'ACGTGGT';

const traslateDna = {
  'G':'C',
  'C':'G',
  'T':'A',
  'A':'U'
}
const toRna = (dna, offset = 0) => {
  if (offset == dna.length) return dna;
  let rnaStr = '';
  rnaStr = dna.substring(0, offset) + traslateDna[dna[offset]] + dna.substring(offset + 1, dna.length);

  return toRna(rnaStr, offset + 1);
};

console.log(toRna(dna));
```

Although, functionally, this method and a loop are equivilant.

Comment: In essence, your just creating a loop. I'm wondering is there a way of doing so without a loop, for example .replace()